# Compile time enum class definition based on template parameters

Tags: c++, enums, c++17

I wonder if there is a way, to enable (or disable) certain values in an enum class declaration, based on  template arguments.

So far the only way I can think of, is to define multiple enums and enable one of them. But in case
of 3 optional values, this would result in 9 enum definitions.

I wonder if there is any other way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Not for a genuine `enum` type. However, you can always use a series of named `static constexpr` integer members of a class to define enumerators. These are a difficult to conditionally define based on template parameters, but it can be done.

The broad structs of such a thing is that each enumerator is a class, and you inherit from it. However, that class is a template class with two implementations conditioned on SFINAE techniques, based on whatever condition you want to define. The one with the passing condition has the `static constexpr` variable; the one with the failing condition is empty.

```
template<typename T, typename U = void>
struct enum1{}; //No enumeration

template<typename T>
struct enum1<T, std::enable_if_t</*condition*/>>
{
    static constexpr int enum_name = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct enumeration: enum1<T>, enum2<T>, ...
{};
```

You can then use `enumeration<Type>::enum_name` if `Type` satisfies the condition. If not, you get a compile error.